# How to change id with JavaScript before submiting HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I created a form where I can fill up some info and submit a file or put a link to add an image.
On my JavaScript code I created a condition to only keep the link to the image if both fields are filled, or if only one is filled than keep that one, that occurs by changing the id on the html. The problem is than when I click on "submit" on the form, the page reloads to send the data to another php file and the JavaScript doesn't have time to run and change de id, so the image isn't saved.
Now I know I'm probably making a newbie mistake but I can't seem to find an answer when doing my research, also I have no idea how to use JQuery, and many of the possible solutions use this.

****Notes:****

1. I used materialize framework to write the form on HTML.
2. I'm still super new to programming, this is the first time writing JS by myself, so there might be some redundant stuff, and the more detailed explanation the better.
3. I've kept some stuff I tried doing while testing.
4. English is not my first language, sorry for any mistakes.
5. Tips are always welcome and thank you so much.

**HTML**

```
<form action="inserirFilme.php" method="POST" id="formulario" onsubmit="alteraIdPoster()">

<!-- ................................................................... NON RELEVANT CODE -->

<div class="file-field input-field">
    <div class="btn blue accent-1">
        <span>Capa</span>
        <input type="file">
    </div>
    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input id="file-filme" class="file-path validate" type="text" name="file-filme">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="file-field input-field">
    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input id="link-filme" class="file-path validate" type="text" name="link-filme">
        <label for="link-filme">Link do pôster do filme</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card-action">
    <a href="index.php" class="waves-effect waves-light btn grey">Cancelar</a>
    <button id="button-enviar" type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue accent-1">Enviar</button>
</div>

</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function alteraIdPoster() {

    const btn = document.getElementById('button-enviar');

    const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-filme');
    const linkInput = document.getElementById('link-filme');

    if (fileInput.value.length !== 0 && linkInput.value.length !== 0) {
        // ️ clear input field
        fileInput.value = '';
        // ️ change id name to poster to work with php
        return linkInput.id = 'poster';
    } else if (fileInput.value.length !== 0 && linkInput.value.length == 0) {
        return fileInput.id = 'poster';
    }
}
```

**I also tried this JavaScript code but then the form wouldn't submit**

```
const btn = document.getElementById('button-enviar');

btn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(event) {

    // ️ if you are submitting a form (prevents page reload)
    event.preventDefault();

    const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-filme');
    const linkInput = document.getElementById('link-filme');

    if (fileInput.value.length !== 0 && linkInput.value.length !== 0) {
        // ️ clear input field
        fileInput.value = '';
        // ️ change id name to poster to work with php
        linkInput.id = 'poster';
        document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
    } else if (fileInput.value.length !== 0 && linkInput.value.length == 0) {
        fileInput.id = 'poster';
        document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: on the 1st example, you are not calling your `alteraIdPoster` function anywhere on the code, so it does nothing

Comment: If you are posting a form, changing the ID of one of the inputs won't make any difference to what the server receives.  Only the name attribute and value of each input are sent.  Maybe you meant to change the name or value to "poster"?

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, I actually erased it while testing and forgot to put it back on the post, if I remember correctly I wrote onsubmit="alteraIdPoster()" on form, but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Comment: @James It's because there will be two optional inputs, a file or a link, I wanted to change the id so the server only receives one of them (if the person put both, the server will only receive the link, if only the file is uploded then the server will only receive the file). 
I have no idea if there's a better way to do that other than changing the id, so the server only stores the one I chose. I tried giving both of then the 'poster' id, but then the server would only store the file.

Comment: @JúliaVieira doing that is not necessary. You just have to change what you send to your form with an if condition

Comment: @ChrisG could you give me an example? Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The form data that gets sent to PHP from each form element are the "name" attribute and the value.  Try changing the name attribute:

```
const btn = document.getElementById('button-enviar');

btn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(event) {

    // ️ if you are submitting a form (prevents page reload)
    event.preventDefault();

    const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-filme');
    const linkInput = document.getElementById('link-filme');

    if (fileInput.value.length !== 0 && linkInput.value.length !== 0) {
        // ️ clear input field
        fileInput.value = '';
        // ️ change NAME to poster.
        linkInput.name = 'poster';
        document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
    } else if (fileInput.value.length !== 0 && linkInput.value.length == 0) {
        fileInput.name = 'poster';
        document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
    }
});
```

Note that PHP won't know if this is a file-filme or a link-filme (unless you have some other way to decide that), it will just handle either file input as "poster".

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, didn't notice that. The only thing is that with this code when I click on the submit button the form isn't sent. I tried removing " event.preventDefault(); " part so the form would be sent but I'm still getting the error "Warning: Undefined array key "poster" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pixar_Catalog\inserirFilme.php on line 6." If it is of any help the repository is on github.com/Lia-Moon/Pixar-Catalog . The only thing is that my commits and some class names are in portuguese hahaha.

Comment: I think that uploaded files should be located in $_FILES not in $_POST.